# using declarations for modifying access specifiers in derived class

Tags: c++

One of the main design principles of C++ as an Object Oriented language is to let each class enforce who can access it's innards and who can't. A base class controls it's access levels even if it is with respect to a base class object embedded within a object of a class derived from Base.

However I read about using declarations that can be allowed to change the access level of a Base class member in a Derived class.

```
class A{
    protected:
    int n;
};

class B:protected A{
    public:
    using  A::n;
};

int main(){
    B obj;
    obj.n=0;
}
```

In the example above, I am changing the access level of a protected member to public in the derived class. Is this allowed on purpose? Why couldn't it be enforced that the access level should be more stringent or equal to how it is in the base class (this can be controlled by the access qualification in the derivation list as well) but cannot be more relaxed than the access level in the base class? Is this allowed because this allows some interesting design patterns? I am just trying to understood why something like this which breaks the principle of encapsulation enforced by a class is allowed?

Comment: Even if it was not possible, you could anyway add public getter/setter in derived class.

Comment: Yes Jarod42. That is possible. But then that still gives the flexibility of allowing the implementation to be changed later as a class with a protected member is likely to be derived from only by the same developer or developers from the same team in all probability. By providing public getters and setters, the implementation details are still controlled by these developers. But by allowing something to be made public, you give the whole world access to your implementation details.

Comment: @user3493289 Now you are mixing two things. Good practices and something being possible or not. Standard and compilers should not restrain and prevent users from hurting themselves, at least it seems like one of the main guidelines of c++. By your logic you could forbid directly exposing properties at all.

Comment: Got it. That does seem to be the case but I was on the receiving end because something like this was allowed. But you guys are misunderstanding my question. I was trying to understand why having a constraint like "access level should not be more relaxed" is going to be a problem. Does allowing a more relaxed access help with something? I know that there are ways to circumvent the C++ safety standards but I am just trying to understand the reasoning behind allowing an access level to be more relaxed.

Comment: To make a point, C++ standards could then have a rule which says "access specifiers lose all their meanings in derived classes and it is up to the derived class writer to specify new access levels". This way C++ standards wouldn't prevent users from shooting themselves in the foot either. But does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that this way you can even change the visibility modifier even if you are not the owner of the base class.
For example if the base class is included in an external library/framework you can change the visibility modifier.

Comment: But that goes against the principle of OOP. If the library designer feels that something should not be accessed then it should remain so. Otherwise you will be making it difficult for him to make any changes to the implementation of his library.

Comment: To tell the truth event getter/setter are violations of information hiding as pointed out by Jarod42

Comment: @user3493289 Well, by this means `struct` isn't OOP compliant as well. C++ allows you to do things that may break classical OOP priniciples.

Comment: Yeah but when someone uses a struct they do it with the knowledge that they are using a default public access level. My question is about allowing changes like above which would make it difficult for the class designer to change his implementation details at a later point of time. By preventing more relaxed access, a class designer does not have to worry about implementation details being leaked online.